# Leer Una Lista de Diccionarios en Python

Tags: python, lista, diccionarios, recursión

Estoy teniendo un lío mental sobre cómo puedo acceder a cada elemento de una lista que dentro tiene diccionarios.

Estoy intentando recursividad pero no comprendo el concepto realmente

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No está claro qué buscas. Primero la imagen es difícil de leer ¿puedes pegar como código el contenido de tu lista? Segundo, los elementos de una lista se acceden poniendo el índice entre corchetes, y los del diccionario poniendo la clave entre corchetes. Y eso vale también si están anidados, así `lista[0]` sería el primer elemento de la lista y si éste es un diccionario que tiene la clave `nombre`, `lista[0]["nombre"]` te daría el valor de esa clave. Tercero, a priori no veo para qué podría servirte la recursividad. Finalmente ¿quieres acceder a un elemento concreto o extraer algo de todos?

Answer (score 1):

Para hacerlo paso a paso y de la manera mas basica posible, primero obtenemos cada elemento de la lista y al interior cada uno de los elementos que componen el diccionario:

```
lista = [{'Nombre':'NUCLEO', 'Id':20, 'Tipo':'MP', 'Fuente':2},{'Nombre':'PVC de mexichem', 'Id':19, 'Tipo':'MP', 'Fuente':2}]

for elem in lista:      #accedemos a cada elemento de la lista (en este caso cada elemento es un dictionario)
    for k,v in elem.items():        #acedemos a cada llave(k), valor(v) de cada diccionario
        print(k, v)
```